# Subclassing PFUser. Accessing current user

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Im trying to subclass PFUser, because I want to add some properties, but I also need that [MyUserSubclass currentUser] return MyUserSubclass istead of PFUser instance.

My current code goes like this:

```
+ (instancetype)currentClient {
    MyUserSubclass *client = [MyUserSubclass objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [client fetch];
    return client;
}
```

At method [client fetch] my app crashes and a console got a warning:Can't refresh an object that hasn't been saved to the server.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check `PFUser.h` in Parse library, you will see `currentUser` returns `instancetype`.

```
+ (instancetype)currentUser;
```

This means that if you subclass `PFUser`, then `currentUser` returns an object of the type of the subclass, which is `MyUserSubclass` in your case.

Here is a short example of subclassing `PFUser`:

`User.h`

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface User : PFUser <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;

+ (User *)user;
+ (BOOL)isLoggedIn;

@end
```

`User.m`

```
#import "User.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation User

@dynamic firstName;

+ (User *)user {
    return (User *)[PFUser user];
}

+ (BOOL)isLoggedIn
{
    return [User currentUser] ? YES: NO;
}

@end
```

Notice that I need to implement a `+(User *)user;` method, because in `PFUser.h` it is `+(PFUser *)user;` rather than `instancetype`.

Comment: Ok I used your help and now the crash dissapear. If I write currentUser to console is shows like this:  
    <PFUser:kS3BVy9rw2:(null)> {
        email = "test@me.com";
        phone = 040820020;
        username = 40820020;
    }  
Is it allright that it writes down PFUser class insteda of KZClient?

Comment: Yes because `currentUser` is internally set to `PFUser` by a login function, which is OK. When you need to use a function in your `KZClient` object, you can cast it to `KZClient`.